# Building a model - based RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, report

### Objective

Build a PDF file which represents single C# class object with multiple fields and properties, that is created in runtime. It constains plain text, variables, tables, images.

### What I have to use?

As a requirement, I have to render PDF report with `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport` and it will probably contain SubReports.

### What I did?

When working with reports until now, following simple pattern was enough:

```
ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter();
param.Name = "Param name";
```

but in that case I'd have to make over 80 parameters and I think it's just not a nice way, so I'm curious if there is better way to do that. Based on my researchers on SO and google, I can use `System.Data.DataSet` to achieve what I want, but:

- It is only sightly better that hardcoding all the parameters
- It is almost the same, but I produce additional files, IMO it's easier to use and understand ReportParameter way for future code users than getting burried in tons of extra files, that(maybe) could have been avoided
- DataSets are for tabular data; I have one big model

### Problem

Actually, I think the problem lies in DataSource of the RDLC report itself. The ways that VS provides are created for DB connection or any DB related object. That's why using DataSources and DataSets is indicated. I can provide any data that is either of type IEnumerable or IReportData (or from db connection), but mine are neither. I got my model already build and I'd want to use it if possible. 
Most examples I found was for creating reports straight from database or custom data sets. Got no more ideas how to make it work. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

When using an external component is an option for you: I've been using the .NET reporting component "combit List & Label". It has PDF export and an object dataprovider included that takes any .NET object or even object structure and provides the object`s properties as variables/parameters in an interactive report designer for tables, charts, etc.